# how to catch sqflite DatabaseException in Dart/Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am unsuccessful at catching an sqflite SQL error that throws a database exception. Note: it's a Future and async.

Sample Code

```
Future<String> getData() async {

Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, globals.databaseName);
Database db = await openDatabase(path);

List results = await db.rawQuery("mal formed example of sql on purpose");
}
```

When I run the code above, rawQuery throws the on-purpose bad SQL.  The console shows:

```
E/SQLiteLog( 7908): (1) near "mal": syntax error
```

What I want to do is be able to catch SQL errors and handle them.

I've tried .then and .catchError - but not getting it to work.

And from what I've read, normal try {} catch {} doesn't work on Futures.  (I did try that to start with... and it didn't work).

```
try {
  List results = await db.rawQuery("mal formed example of sql on purpose");
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

results in the same error:

```
E/SQLiteLog( 3148): (1) near "mal": syntax error
```

Comment: If you use `async`/`await` you can just use `try`/`catch`

Comment: I tried that...  (as I mentioned in the last sentence above).

try {
    List results = await db.rawQuery("mal formed example of sql on purpose");
} catch (e) {
    print(e);
}

returns the same error

E/SQLiteLog( 3148): (1) near "mal": syntax error

I'm looking for a try catch scenario that works.

Comment: Please post the code that shows what you tried

Comment: added the code in the original post above.

Comment: Looks like the exception is not propagated to Dart. Don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the issue got fixed by upgrading to the latest version (don't know which version was used in the reported issue): https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/17

The SQLException (iOS and Android) is propagated to Dart and can be caught as a DatabaseException using try/catch when using async/await, as shown in the test here: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/example/lib/exception_test_page.dart#L89-L94